# jQuery-ui datepicker : localization doesn't work when using setDate

Tags: jquery, localization, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I pick the date, the language is OK (french), but the default value (set by the setDate method) is still in english. Anyone has an idea ?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My DatePicker</title>
    <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<input type="text" name="datEnq" id="xxx" readonly /> 
<script>
$("#xxx").datepicker();
$("#xxx").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "d MM yy");
$("#xxx").datepicker("setDate", "0");
</script>
```

[image: jQuery datepicker]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the localization:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KD84f/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is what I did, I checked several times, this does not solve the problem (besides, this line $.datepicker.regional is already included in the ...-fr.js file)

Comment: In the fiddle I used I had to explicitly call that, otherwise it was not being set. If that's not the problem, I'd say the real problem lies elsewhere. (maybe in some code you didn't post?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I figured it out : in `query.ui.datepicker-fr.js` localization values are inside a **onLoad** block, thus any code using the localization directly (like *setDate*) must also be in a **onLoad** block, otherwise the datepicker is still in english.

So use:

```
$(function(){
  $("#xxx").datepicker();
  $("#xxx").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "d MM yy");
  $("#xxx").datepicker("setDate", "0");
});
```